# How to store a label control text into a textbox control value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label

I am trying to set the value of a textbox control in my aspx page as the value of a label text. I am using the following code but nothing happens. I have tried from the code behind file using c# and then I want to assign the textbox value to a session variable. If I just assign a string value like "Hello" it works, but otherwise nothing works.

So this is the markup:

```
         <asp:Label ID="blbtest" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"> 
         </asp:Label>
         <asp:Button ID="btnBook" runat="server" Text="Book Now" 
          CssClass="spaces-info__button" OnClick="btnBook_Click"/>
    
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtmtcid" runat="server"> 
         </asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        if (!(Session["username"] == null))
        {
            string usn = Session["username"].ToString();
            lblusn.Text = usn;      
        }

    }
 protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtmtcid.Text = blbtest.Text;
        Session["mtcid"] = txtmtcid.Text;
        Response.Redirect("booknow.aspx");
    }
```

Updated JS:

```
    $(function () {
    //dom is ready
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
var usn = document.getElementById('lblusn').innerHTML;

console.log(usn);

request.open('GET', "URL" + usn + ""); //of course I have replaced 
    the URL here
    request.onload = function () {
    var response = request.response;
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(parsedData);
    var nm = parsedData.fullName;
    document.getElementById('lblfullnm').innerHTML = nm;
    var mtcid = parsedData.employeeCode;
    document.getElementById('blbtest').innerHTML = mtcid;
    document.getElementById('txtmtcid').value = 
 document.getElementById('blbtest').innerHTML
};
request.send();
    });
```

I am new to JS, and asp.net, so trying to browse whatever possible and work things out here. The session variable value is just not getting passed to next page. Honestly, I don't need the textbox, I don't know if label text can be stored in session variables. If that's possible, then all I want to do is assign the blbtest label text to the session variable, but that also didn't work, but if I am hard coding it like:

```
    Session["mtcid"]="D-11234"
```

this works and the value of session variable is passed.

Hence I am trying now with textbox. Is there a better approach to this?

If there is a way to avoid the use of the label and textbox and simply pass the session variable, Session["username"] from the code behind to the JavaScript, that would be great.

This was my previous post, I am reposting since I didn't receive much help. I realised that on button click, the values in the label controls and the Session variable are getting lost, how can I deal with this?

I have made these changes to my project now:

```
     <asp:Label ID="lblusn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
     style="display: none;"></asp:Label>

     <script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>

  <asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="static" ID="hiddenmtcid" runat="server" />

  <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center coltitle">          
                
                <h2><asp:Label ID="blbtest" runat="server" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfullnm" runat="server" 
    ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                </h2>
```

Code behind:

```
    namespace LRC_Spaces_Booking_System
    {
    public partial class userdashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
    

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //if (!(Session["username"] == null))
        //{
        //  lblusn.Text = Session["username"].ToString();
        //}
            
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
                if (Session["username"] == null)
                {
                    // session not passed, so let's jump back to page 1
                    Response.Redirect("userlogin.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblusn.Text = Session["username"] as string;
                    Session["mtcid"] = blbtest.Text;

                }
            
        }
        

    }

    protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //lblusn.Text = hiddenusn.Value;
        //Session["mtcid"] = hiddenmtcid.Value; 
        //Response.Redirect("booknow.aspx");        
        //// take lable value - shove back into session
        
        Response.Redirect("booknow.aspx");
    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


}
```

JavaScript:

```
        $(function () {
      //dom is ready
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
      var hiddenusn = document.getElementById('lblusn').innerHTML;
      
      request.open('GET',"https://qr.mtc.edu.om/api/public/hrmsInfo/qZ3sDDUVdhvhFQgF5XSVeJPsPp3Hvy9E/" + hiddenusn + "");
    request.onload = function () {
    var response = request.response;
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(parsedData);
    var nm = parsedData.fullName;
    document.getElementById('lblfullnm').innerHTML = nm;
    var mtcid = parsedData.employeeCode;
    document.getElementById('blbtest').innerHTML = mtcid;
    
    //console.log(document.getElementById('hiddenmtcid').value);
  };
  request.send();
  });
```

Comment: `var MyJavaScriptVariable = '<%= Session["username"] %>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a whack at this again.

> Honestly, I don't need the textbox, I don't know if label text can be stored in session variables

OK, then it is in session, so the next page you jump to does not care, or have to know anything about the current page, right? If the value is ALREADY in session, then why do we care about this current page?

And what's the goal with your posted JS routine? That looks like a web method call? Why, and what is that supposed to do?

And why is usn being passed with that "post" routine to the server when we already admitted that the server session has this value?

The code behind can freely use that session() value, so why then is that usn being passed to some server side routine? I don’t grasp the goal here. Perhaps you calling some web method, but the web method has use of session, so this begs the question why usn is being passed in that URL and web method?

> I don't know if label text can be stored in session variables

It certainly can can be. But the $100 question is DOES the client side code in the page EVER need to use that value? That really is the question here. If it does, then you can place that value into a label, text box, or MORE common is to use a hidden field control. (they all can be used - but if you not look to display that value on the page, then you could I suppose "hide" the label, or text box (style="display:none"), but hidden field would be better since it is already hidden.

So, the ONLY reason to send and place that session() value into the client side markup would be if local JS code (as opposed to server side code) needs that value.

Since the value is in session(), then ANY kind of navigation to any other page? It can use that value in session(). You have zero need to pass the value in some URL parameters or whatever.

So, it's not clear if this value is required client side. I guess, I have to assume some place, and some where that value is required for use in client-side JS code.

Or, maybe the client side code needs to CHANGE this value, and then that value needs to be passed to the next page?

So, if we need to use/see/have that session value client side?

Well, OK, then say we have this simple markup: three buttons.

- One to show the label value as is.
- One button to CHANGE the label value (100% client side code).
- And a third button you can click, that will take this (possible) label value, and shove it back into session.

Perhaps you're not grasping the difference between client-side code, and server-side?

Anyway, so we have this (and I am using jQuery - it usually installed by default, and it does make referencing of client side controls a whole lot easer. (and it should be installed by default for your project).

So, here is our markup:

```
         <asp:Label ID="blbtest" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"> 
         </asp:Label>
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdShow" runat="server" Text="Show label value - client side code"
            OnClientClick="showlvalue();return false" CssClass="btn"
            />
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdchange" runat="server" Text="change client side label value"
            OnClientClick="changevalue();return false" CssClass="btn"
            />
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdJump" runat="server" Text="Jump to next page with modifed lable into session" OnClick="cmdJump_Click" />

        <script>

            function showlvalue() {
                alert($('#blbtest').text())
            }

            function changevalue() {
                var sNew = prompt("enter new value for label")
                $('#blbtest').text(sNew)
            }

        </script>
```

And our code behind is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["FunTest"] = "this is session";
            blbtest.Text = Session["FunTest"] as string;
        }
    }

    protected void cmdJump_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // take lable value - shove back into session
        Session["FunTest"] = blbtest.Text;
        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
    }
```

So, now we have this:

[image]

OK, let's click on first button, we get this:

[image]

Now, let's click on the second value, change the label (but, it ONLY occurring client side)

[image]

So, above "zoo zoo zoo", when I hit OK, it will shove that result BACK into the label. (but it STILL NOT in the session() yet).

We now have this:

[image]

So, at this point, the browser and this markup is still 100% client side - we have NOT interacted with the server. And we have to be careful, since any standard button click WILL trigger the page load event EACH time, and THEN run your code stub. However, we have that all important !IsPostBack code test and stub - it is critical to have that code stub, and 99% of all my pages use that code stub for setup. If I don't use that ispostback check, then when we click the third button above, the page load event fires FIRST and THEN our button event. So, page load ALWAYS triggers for each server side post-back and button event (or any other event).

So, at this point we changed the label - client side code. Now, we can click our third button - the server side button.

Note how it takes the value from the label, shoves BACK into session(), and THEN we jump to the next page in question. that target page of course can now use session(), since we moved/shoved/transferred the value in the label back into session.

And be careful. What happens if our button on the client side is a hyper link, or navigates to the second (target) page in place of server side code? Well, then our label value will NEVER make it back into session, since we MUST have a post-back in the current page. the current page travels back up to server, code behind runs (transfer label back into session(), and THEN we execute a response.redirect to the next page.

Obviously in above, we can't jump to the next page without a post back.

However, can we work and do this 100% without ANY controls on the page, and without that label value?

Sure, we can add web methods to the page. We can write a web method to get that session value. and we can even write a web method to modify the session() value if we want.

Note that as I suggested, since that label should be hidden, then I suggest dropping in a asp.net hidden field - they are both client side and server side friendly, and are hidden for you.

But, for jQuery, keep in mind:

```
 for TextBox  - use .val() to get (or set a text box)
 for Label - use .text() to get (or set a label)
 for hidden field, use .val()
```

and our target page - that we jump to based on hitting third button, it can display that session value in a label.

Say this markup:

```
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

And code behind for second page

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["FunTest"] == null)
            {
                // session not passed, so let's jump back to page 1
                Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = Session["FunTest"] as string;
            }
        }

    }
```

## Edit: Get any session value - as string with web method

So, in place of setting some value on the page, you can in JavaScript simple CALL a custom web method you create, and with two web methods, you can set, or get a session value.

Now, you can build a asmx page - for your web methods, but let's just drop the two methods right into our existing page.

So, for testing, we have this:

```
        <div style="font-size:large;text-align:right;width:30%">
        <p>enter Session key:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>Enter Session value:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSetValue" runat="server" Text="Send/save value to session" cssclass="btn"
            OnClientClick="setSession();return false;" />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdGetValue" runat="server" Text="Get a session value" CssClass="btn"
            style="margin-left:25px"
            OnClientClick="getSession();return false" />

        <script>
            function setSession() {
                MyKey = $('#TextBox1').val()
                MyValue = $('#TextBox2').val()
                //MyURLMethod = "WebForm2.aspx/SetSession"
                MyURLMethod = $(location).attr('pathname') + "/SetSession"
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: MyURLMethod,
                    data: JSON.stringify({sKey: MyKey, sValue : MyValue}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert('session value set')
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                    }
                });
            }

            function getSession() {

                MyURLMethod = $(location).attr('pathname') + "/GetSession"

                MyKey = prompt("What session key to get?")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: MyURLMethod,
                    data: JSON.stringify({sKey : MyKey}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (mydata) {
                        alert('session key value = ' + mydata.d)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Our code behind, not much, but this:

```
    // using System.Web.Services;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }


    [WebMethod(enableSession:true)]
    public static void SetSession(string sKey, string sValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[sKey] = sValue;
    }

    [WebMethod(enableSession:true)]
    public static string GetSession(string sKey)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[sKey] as string;
    }
```

OK, so now with the above two routines, we can set a value, or get a value to-from sesson[], and do so with JS code.

I'm using jQuery, but you get the idea here:

We get this:

[image]

So, I entered "MyName" as the session key, and then my name, and hit my first button.

Now, I can click on the second button, we get this:

[image]

And OK, and I get this:

[image]

So, all I am saying, is you CAN add some web methods to a page, and those web methods are free to get/grab or set a session value.

Comment: Hi Albert. Thank you so much for the detailed answer. So, I realised the usn in code behind was not needed, i deleted it. I have a login form before this aspx page, and I got access to the Web API from the IT department to display some profile info for the logged in user in the label controls. blbtest displays the employee's code.

Comment: basically, im  using one session variable "username" to store its value in lblusn which is used in the js to call the webapi, and second session variable "mtcid" whose value is equal to hiddenfield value(which should be getting its value from the blbtest label control, which I assign in the js. ) is the one being passed to the next page. but, on button click, the hiddenfield value null is stored in the session variable and sent to next page.

Comment: protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Session["mtcid"] = hiddenmtcid.Value; Response.Redirect("booknow.aspx"); }

Comment: No problem. In fact we CAN actually make a simple webmethod, and pass it a string session "key" value, and have it return the session value. So, you could make 2 js routines. One to set a session value (pass it key, and value),  and one to get/grab a session value. With those two routines, you would have full use of session() in your client side code. You thus would not need to setup or use any hidden control on the given web page.

Comment: Do you mean I pass the session from the login page first, then from the next page to the third page? On my third page, I will be adding records to SQL database, with one of the values as the MTCID session variable, can I still use the js session variables in that case?

Comment: Well, as noted, server side - always you have session. If some particular page sets the session as we did, then you good to go. HOWEVER, DO look at the edit I just made. I did add a Get and set the session from JavaScript code direclty, and without having to put hidden controls on the web page. It really depends on what you want to do. You have MORE ways to approach this issue then you do flavors of ice cream. What road will really depend on what you doing. But, you can set (or get) session values from js code - you just have to add two web methods for this purpose.

Comment: But, yes, to answer your question - yes, once in session() you can use it any where, any page - it persists at server side. In fact, this may well suggest that you NEVER need that value in client side code - and if you can avoid as such, you should.  That session get/set code is a bit dangerous, and if one was to do that, I would not allow passing of a "key" value, since then any one modifying the js code could get and set any session() value they want. Session() is your friend, since it server side - and safe and secure. but, I posted that example getSession() just to give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, now i passed the session variable to the third page, using js, and it seems to work. in the js of the third page, i am storing that session value in a label control, and when a button to add records to the sql database is clicked, all other values on the page are added to the database record, except for this label control value, which is for some reason becoming null.

Comment: $(function () {
var mtcid = localStorage.getItem('mtcid');
    console.log(mtcid);
    document.getElementById('lblmtcid').innerHTML = mtcid;
});    this is working fine. I can see the label control text as desired

Comment: But this line of code, sends null value to the database: sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MTC_ID", lblmtcid.Text);

Comment: how can i prevent the label control values from being lost on button click?

Comment: Lables set by client side js code do NOT persist - their view state is not going to be up-dated. Use a text box, or a hidden field. label values set in code behind WILL persist, but not when changed by client side js code. So, as noted, use a text box (style it as a label if you need it to display, or better yet use a asp.net hidden field. So, labels are for display, and not in general to be used for passing values around. So, text box, hidden field? -- yes WHEN changed by client side code, on post back, then code behind will see the js changes that occurred client side - labels will not.

Comment: Use both a label, and asp.net hidden field. Have your client side js code always set both - label for display, and hidden field for code behind. Lables don't automatic update what is called "viewstate" (automatic system that persists the controls). So, if client side js code modifies the label, then code behind will not see that change. So, either use a text box, or as noted use both a hidden field and label (to allow code behind to see this change), or use a textbox in place of a label. js changes to labels not seen by code behind. Labels are for display, not storing/passing values around.

Comment: Thanks Albert. now I added a textbox on the third page, as well as a hidden field,  only to check . i dont really want the textbox to be displayed though. in js i have assigned session value to the textbox as well as the hidden field, but i get this error: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value') i have tried placing the script before declaring the controls, after and at the end of the document, but doesnt work.  Oh I also added a label control, the session value is displayed in the label but I cant assign that to  the textbox or hidden field both in js and code behind. it shows null.

Comment: $(function () {
var mtcid = localStorage.getItem('mtcid');
    console.log(mtcid);
    document.getElementById('lblmtcid').innerHTML = mtcid;
    document.getElementById('hiddenmtcid').value = mtcid;
    document.getElementById('txtmtcid').value = mtcid || {};
    console.log(document.getElementById('txtmtcid').value);
  
});

Comment: I realised i missed out the ClientIDMode attribute: ClientIDMode="Static"..its working now! I was able to save the record successfully. Thank you very much Albert for your help.! God bless you :)

Comment: Most welcome. Do keep in mind it was my bad mistake that label control would persist and allow client side update to be seen by server side. That was incorrect. While text box and hidden control works, a label does not.(client side modify is not seen server side - I didn't realize that). So if you really need label display then use both hidden field control for passing to code behind and only use label for display). I do this all the time but in fact never did this with labels - so was wrong in regards to client side labels - but text box or hidden field does work. Clientidmode is good idea

Comment: thanks. Taken your advise and its working great!